# how to load part of the layout content alone

Tags: android

Friend's
  I need help on loading the content alone in my page without going to new page when i selected the scroll menu.

**>  I have an

> ```
>      1. header layout and 
>      2. framelayout in another xml file have declared Listview and it
> ```
>
> also have tabhost
>               **and also have gallery view for scroll menu.
>            3. content list in another xml file.****

when i selected the scroll menu i need to load the list content alone in that activity i suppose not to load whole header and and redeclare tabhost in next that scroll menu selected activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this effect by having everything defined in a single xml file with multiple `TableLayout` views stacked on top of each other within a `Merge` view.  In order to "load" a view, I change its `Android:visibility` tag from `"gone"` to `"visible"`.  Since you want your second view to not obscure the header, you can put a buffer (margin or padding) that offsets it from the top of the screen.  The background color of this top `TableLayout` would have to be `android:background="#00000000"` so that the alpha channel is zero and it is transparent.

If anyone else has a more elegant approach, I would be interested to know as well, but this suites me just fine.  The only downside I see is an extra large XML file.